# Как стереть последний символ в Entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

код:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()

root.title('Калькулятор')
root.resizable(False, False)
root["bg"] = "white"

'''
Функции которые пишут:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,+,-,*,/ и решают прымер
'''
def b1():#Пишет 1
    e.insert(END, '1')
def b2():#Пишет 2
    e.insert(END, '2')
def b3():#Пишет 3
    e.insert(END, '3')
def b4():#Пишет 4
    e.insert(END, '4')
def b5():#Пишет 5
    e.insert(END, '5')
def b6():#Пишет 6
    e.insert(END, '6')
def b7():#Пишет 7
    e.insert(END, '7')
def b8():#Пишет 8
    e.insert(END, '8')
def b9():#Пишет 9
    e.insert(END, '9')
def b0():#Пишет 0
    e.insert(END, '0')
def b_plus():#Пишет +
    e.insert(END, '+')
def b_minus():#Пишет -
    e.insert(END, '-')
def b_multiply():#Пишет *
    e.insert(END, '*')
def b_division():#Пишет /
    e.insert(END, '/')
def b_clean():#Всё стирает
    e.delete(0, END)
def b_clean1():#Стирает один символ
    e.delete(END)
def b_float():#Пишет .
    e.insert(END, '.')
def b_is():#Решает прымер
    try:
        a = e.get()
        otvet = eval(a)
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, otvet )
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
        
'''Функции для ковертера температур'''
def f_in_c():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a=int(a)
        c = (a-32)/1.8
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def c_in_f():
    try:    
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = (a*1.8)+32
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 


"""Функции для конвертера масс"""

def kar_in_g():
    try:    
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*0.2
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)

    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def g_in_kar():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*5
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)

    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def N_in_g():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*101.971601
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def g_in_N():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*0.009807
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)

    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def lb_in_g():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*453.59237
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def g_in_lb():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a*0.00220462262
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )

'''Фукції для іншого'''

def rad_in_gradus():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = (a*180)/3.14
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' ) 
def gradus_in_rad():
    try:
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = (a*3.14)/180
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)    
    except:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, 'Некоректные данны' )
def x_y():
    e.insert(END, '**')
def x_2():
        a = e.get()
        a = eval(a)
        a = int(a)
        c = a**(1/2)
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(END, c)



pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)



e = Entry(bd=3)#Строка для вывода данных

'''Все кнопки с цифрами и +,-,*,/,=,C'''
b1 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=38, compound="c", image=pixel, text='1', command=b1, relief = FLAT, activebackground='white')
b2 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=38, compound="c", image=pixel, text='2', command=b2, relief = FLAT)
b3 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=38, compound="c", image=pixel, text='3', command=b3, relief = FLAT)
b4 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=39, compound="c", image=pixel, text='4', command=b4, relief = FLAT)
b5 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=39, compound="c", image=pixel, text='5', command=b5, relief = FLAT)
b6 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=39, compound="c", image=pixel, text='6', command=b6, relief = FLAT)
b7 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=40, compound="c", image=pixel, text='7', command=b7, relief = FLAT)
b8 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=40, compound="c", image=pixel, text='8', command=b8, relief = FLAT)
b9 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=40, compound="c", image=pixel, text='9', command=b9, relief = FLAT)
b0 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=45, compound="c", image=pixel, text='0', command=b0, relief = FLAT)
b_plus = Button(bg ='orange', width=36, height=43, compound="c", image=pixel, text='+', relief = FLAT, command = b_plus)
b_minus = Button(bg ='orange', width=36, height=43, compound="c", image=pixel, text='-', relief = FLAT, command = b_minus)
b_clean = Button(bg ='yellow', width=37, height=43, compound="c", image=pixel, text='C', relief = FLAT, command = b_clean)
b_clean1 = Button(bg ='yellow', width=36, height=43, compound="c", image=pixel, text='→', relief = FLAT, command = b_clean1)
b_multiply = Button(bg = 'orange', height=97, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text='*', relief = FLAT, command = b_multiply)
b_division = Button(bg ='orange', height=93, width=35, compound="c", image=pixel, text=':', relief = FLAT, command = b_division)
b_is = Button(bg = '#FFA07A', width=37, height=45, compound="c", image=pixel, text='=', relief = FLAT, command = b_is)
b_float = Button(bg ='lightgreen', width=36, height=45, compound="c", image=pixel, text='.', relief = FLAT, command = b_float)


'''Кнопки конвертера тамператур'''
l_t = Label(text='Температура', anchor=N, height=2, bg='white')
c_in_f = Button( text='C→F', command=c_in_f, compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=37, relief = FLAT, bg='lightblue')
f_in_c = Button( text='F→C', command=f_in_c, compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=37, relief = FLAT, bg='lightblue')


'''Кнопки конвертера масс'''
l_m = Label(text='Масса', anchor=N, height=2, bg='white')
kar_in_g = Button( text='кар→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=41, command=kar_in_g, relief = FLAT, bg='green')
g_in_kar = Button( text='г→кар', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=41, command=g_in_kar, relief = FLAT, bg='green')
N_in_g = Button(text='Н→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=38, command = N_in_g, relief = FLAT, bg='green')
g_in_N = Button(text='г→Н', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=38, command = g_in_N, relief = FLAT, bg='green')
lb_in_g = Button(text='фунти→г', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=44, command = lb_in_g, relief = FLAT, bg='green')
g_in_lb = Button(text='г→фунти', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=44, command = g_in_lb, relief = FLAT, bg='green')

'''Трикутник'''
trik_text = Label(text='Трикутник', anchor=S, height=3, bg='white')
cos = Button(text='cos', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=44, relief = FLAT, bg='red')
sin = Button(text='sin', compound="c", image=pixel, width=40, height=44, relief = FLAT, bg='red')


"""Інше"""
other_text = Label(text='Інше', anchor=N, height=2, bg='white')
v1 = Button(text='км/год', compound="c", image=pixel, width=38, height=38, relief = FLAT, bg='pink')
v2 = Button(text='м/c', compound="c", image=pixel, width=38, height=38, relief = FLAT, bg='pink')
x_2 = Button(text='²√x', compound="c", image=pixel, width=38, height=40, relief = FLAT, bg='pink')
x_y = Button(text='xʸ', compound="c", image=pixel, width=38, height=40, relief = FLAT, bg='pink', command=x_y)
rad_in_gradus = Button(text='рад→x°', compound="c", image=pixel, width=38, height=37, relief = FLAT, bg='pink', command=rad_in_gradus)
gradus_in_rad = Button(text='x°→рад', compound="c", image=pixel, width=38, height=37, relief = FLAT, bg='pink', command=gradus_in_rad)






'''С помощью функции grid() упаковуем все виджети '''

'''Температура'''
l_t.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=4)
c_in_f.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
f_in_c.grid(row=1, column=6, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,ipady=0)

'''Масса'''
l_m.grid(row=2, column=4,rowspan=2, columnspan=4)
kar_in_g.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=2)
g_in_kar.grid(row=3, column=6, columnspan=2)
N_in_g.grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=2)
g_in_N.grid(row=4, column=6, columnspan=2)
lb_in_g.grid(row=5, column=4, columnspan=2)
g_in_lb.grid(row=5, column=6, columnspan=2)

'''Трикутник'''
trik_text.grid(row=4, column=8, columnspan=4) 
cos.grid(row=5, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
sin.grid(row=5, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)


"""Інше"""
other_text.grid(row=1, column=8, columnspan=4, pady=10) 
v1.grid(row=1, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
v2.grid(row=1, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
x_2.grid(row=2, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
x_y.grid(row=2, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
rad_in_gradus.grid(row=3, column=8, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)
gradus_in_rad.grid(row=3, column=10, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=0)




b_clean.grid(row=1, column=2)
b_clean1.grid(row=1, column=3)
b_plus.grid(row=1, column=0)
b_minus.grid(row=1, column=1)
b_division.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=2)
b_multiply.grid(row=4, column=3, rowspan=2)
b_is.grid(row=5, column=2)
b_float.grid(row=5, column=1)
b1.grid(row=2, column=0)
b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
b3.grid(row=2, column=2)
b4.grid(row=3, column=0)
b5.grid(row=3, column=1)
b6.grid(row=3, column=2)
b7.grid(row=4, column=0)
b8.grid(row=4, column=1)
b9.grid(row=4, column=2)
b0.grid(row=5, column=0)
e.grid(ipady=10, ipadx=178, row=0, column=0, columnspan=12)

root.mainloop()
```

Нужно настроить функцию b_clean1 что бы она стирала последний символ в строке

Answer (score 2):

Метод `delete` удаляет элемент из `entry` между указанными индексами (если указано два индекса) или от указанного индекса до конца. Нам нужно удалить с последнего символа до конца. Чтобы узнать, с какого индекса удалять, нужно сначала получить текст из текстового поля (`entry.get()`), узнать его длину, вычесть 1 - это и будет индекс последнего символа.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry()
entry.pack()

Button(text="+", command=lambda: entry.insert(END, "+")).pack()
Button(text="-", command=lambda: entry.delete(len(entry.get())-1)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Еще один способ удаления последнего символа (взято [отсюда](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ngdkmk/how_do_you_delete_the_last_character_you_typed_in/gyyl6dk/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)):

```
entry.delete(entry.index(END) - 1)
```

---

Кстати, для всех кнопок с цифрами и знаками действий (кроме `'='`) можно использовать один общий обработчик:

```
def insert_char(char):
    e.insert(END, char)

...

b1 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=38, compound="c", image=pixel, text='1', command=lambda: insert_char('1'), relief = FLAT, activebackground='white')
b2 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=38, compound="c", image=pixel, text='2', command=lambda: insert_char('2'), relief = FLAT)
b3 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=38, compound="c", image=pixel, text='3', command=lambda: insert_char('3'), relief = FLAT)
b4 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=39, compound="c", image=pixel, text='4', command=lambda: insert_char('4'), relief = FLAT)
b5 = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=39, compound="c", image=pixel, text='5', command=lambda: insert_char('5'), relief = FLAT)
...
b_float = Button(bg ='lightgreen', width=36, height=45, compound="c", image=pixel, text='.', relief = FLAT, command=lambda: insert_char('.'))
```

Также можно добавлять эти кнопки циклом:

```
buttons = []
chars = '1234567890+-*/'

for char in chars:
    button = Button(bg = 'lightgreen', width=36, height=38, compound="c", image=pixel, text=char, command=lambda c=char: e.insert(END, с), relief = FLAT)
    buttons.append(button)

...

positions = [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]  # Добавил позиции только для трех кнопок, но дальше смысл тот же

for i, (row, column) in enumerate(positions):
    button[i].grid(row=row, column=column)
```